# MongoDB: Ordered matching of array entries

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which looks like this:

```
"tokens":
[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "word": "I",
    "pos": "NNP",
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "word": "played",
    "pos": "VBZ",
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "word": "football",
    "pos": "IN",
  }
]
```

And my query is:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {
            'tokens.word': 'I'
        },
        {
            tokens: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    word: /f.*/,
                    pos: 'IN'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

The output of my query is the document above. But the result should be no match in this case as I'm searching for

> word: "I" **followed by** [word: /f.*/ and pos:'IN']

which doesn't match the `tokens` array in the document since the token `I` is followed by `played` and then `football`. However, in the query the order of the filters is different as the searching is started with

> word: "I"

followed by

> f.*

[football in this case].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$and` operator is a purely logical one where **the order of the filter conditions does not play any role**.

So the following queries are absolutely equivalent from a result set point of view:

```
$and: [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "b": 2 }
]

$and: [
    { "b": 2 },
    { "a": 1 }
]
```

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) states:

> $and performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more
>   expressions (e.g. , , etc.) and selects the
>   documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array. The $and
>   operator uses short-circuit evaluation. If the first expression (e.g.
>   ) evaluates to false, MongoDB will not evaluate the
>   remaining expressions.

In your example, the `"index1"` entry matches the first filter `"tokens.word": "I"` and the `"index3"` document matches the second `$elemMatch` filter. So the document has to get returned.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an idea - more of a starting point really - for you to get closer to what you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: { // create a temporary field 
        "differenceBetweenMatchPositions": { // called "differenceBetweenMatchPositions"
            $subtract: [ // which holds the difference between
                { $indexOfArray: [ "$tokens.word", "I" ] }, // the index of first element matching first condition and
                { $min: { // the lowest index of
                    $filter: { // a filtered array
                        input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$tokens" } ] }, // that holds the indices [ 0, 1, 2, ..., n ] where n is the number of items in the "tokens" array - 1
                        as: "this", // which we want to access using "$$this"
                        cond: {
                            $let: {
                                vars: { "elem": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$tokens", "$$this" ] } }, // get the n-th element in our "tokens" array
                                in: {
                                    $and: [
                                        { $eq: [ "$$elem.pos", "IN" ] }, // "pos" field must be "IN"
                                        { $eq: [ { $substrBytes: [ "$$elem.word", 0, 1 ] }, "f" ] } // 1st character of the "word" must be "f"
                                    ] 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "differenceBetweenMatchPositions": { $lt: 0 } // we only want documents where the first condition is matched by an item in our array before the second one gets matched, too.
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. How I can solve this issue ? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What precisely should your filter do?

Comment: if my filter is word:"I" &[word:/p.*/ & pos:"VBZ"] then the output should be I played football in which played in a json file has a pos:"VBZ" but when I put a query search word:"I" & [word:/f.*/ & pos:"IN"] then I don't need any output [I played football in which football has a pos:IN I don't need it in this case to be in the output as the order is different and not exact match.

Comment: I appreciate your help. According to your query, Could you please explain how I can change easily this query if I want to add more conditions like A B C in which A after that B after that C.

Comment: from you query you take the first element and compare it to every element in the array but if i want to add more one condition ?

Comment: I was hoping you would not ask that question since my approach is not particularly generic. So you'd really need to work through your specific case to make things work. You can, of course, follow the same logic to find the lowest index of all items matching any filter condition and then do the Maths like I did above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it do you think translate it from php would be complicated in this case